# How to get UFW in Ubuntu 20.10 (Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded)

Tags: kernel, iptables, 20.10

This is my Ubuntu 20.10, if I understand uname show wrong version

```
# uname -r
4.15.0-60-generic
```

because

```
# ls -la /boot
total 147492
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Feb 11 21:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root     4096 Feb 11 01:07 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   248258 Jan 18 17:01 config-5.8.0-41-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   248258 Feb  5 03:41 config-5.8.0-43-generic
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Feb 11 21:21 grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 Feb 11 21:21 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.8.0-43-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 55795996 Feb 11 01:07 initrd.img-5.8.0-41-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 55798352 Feb 11 21:21 initrd.img-5.8.0-43-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 Jan 28 07:27 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.8.0-41-generic
drwx------  2 root root    16384 Feb 11 01:07 lost+found
-rw-------  1 root root  5635676 Jan 18 17:01 System.map-5.8.0-41-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  5635676 Feb  5 03:41 System.map-5.8.0-43-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 Feb 11 21:21 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.8.0-43-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 13715296 Jan 18 17:08 vmlinuz-5.8.0-41-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 13715296 Feb  5 04:04 vmlinuz-5.8.0-43-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 Jan 28 07:27 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.8.0-41-generic
```

```
 # dpkg -l | grep linux-
ii  linux-base                           4.5ubuntu4                        all          Linux image base package
ii  linux-firmware                       1.190.3                           all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-generic                        5.8.0.43.48                       amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-5.8.0-41               5.8.0-41.46                       all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.8.0
ii  linux-headers-5.8.0-41-generic       5.8.0-41.46                       amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.8.0-43               5.8.0-43.49                       all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.8.0
ii  linux-headers-5.8.0-43-generic       5.8.0-43.49                       amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                5.8.0.43.48                       amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-image-5.8.0-41-generic         5.8.0-41.46                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic         5.8.0-43.49                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                  5.8.0.43.48                       amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-modules-5.8.0-41-generic       5.8.0-41.46                       amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.8.0-43-generic       5.8.0-43.49                       amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-41-generic 5.8.0-41.46                       amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-43-generic 5.8.0-43.49                       amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

```
 #  ls -lha /lib/modules
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Feb 11 21:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 47 root root 4.0K Feb 11 21:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Jan 28 07:27 5.8.0-41-generic
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Feb 11 21:21 5.8.0-43-generic
```

When I try to install UFW, I receive error
**error: couldn't determine iptables version**
I have seen iptables version

```
# update-alternatives --list iptables
   /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
   /usr/sbin/iptables-nft
```

and switch to old version

```
# update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
```

and reboot.
But UFW still don't working.

```
 # sudo iptables --list
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-60-generic
iptables v1.8.5 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

```
# depmod
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-60-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
```

```
 # ufw status verbose
ERROR: problem running iptables: modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-60-generic
iptables v1.8.5 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

How to repair this ubuntu (see Uname) and install UFW in correct way?

Comment: Looks like you should reboot to boot into new kernel, did you just upgraded to 20.10 and never rebooted since?

Comment: @mook765 reboted, no change

Comment: I do not know how you can be running 4.15.0-60-generic, but it doesn't show in the dpkg list.

Comment: @DougSmythies I do not made anything special, this is standard official cloud Ubuntu 20.10 from Hetzner datacenter. I activate cloud VM than done only apt update and apt upgrade. Than try to install UFW, but failed.

Comment: yes, that is really important information. Often hosted sites force the kernel and have issues with either no iptables at all or version issues.

Comment: @DougSmythies 16.04 in that cloud provider has correct kernel, but I must use exactly 20.10 and now i'm in frustration because I don't understand how to repair this distribution, I must set up KVM, Docker and many-many other future in this Ubuntu, but even simplest command like UNAME and UFW don't working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

and finally I have understand this issue. This is all we know about cloud providers, their scripts set up operation system to one disk (in my case /dev/sdb Ubuntu 20.10) than booting system from another disk (in my case /dev/sda with Ubuntu 16.04)